# Remove LayerSlider WP gap on the left

Tags: css, plugins, wordpress

I am dealing with this problem for weeks.
 If you see on the top of my blog http://draidel.com.ar/novedades/ you will notice the there is a gap on the left. 
 I already consulted the support team of Kresi (The 3rd party company who included this plugin into their theme) but they couldn't find a solution yet.
 This is the link for the ticket I submitted to them (http://www.kriesi.at/support/topic/layerslider-gap-on-the-left/).

I guess this might have something to do with the fact that it's set to dynamically show new posts because this didn't happen to me with other banners I created (same plugin)

Any idea ?

Thanks !

Ariel

Comment: I see all sorts of garbage and errors in there. However which part is the part that has the space you're trying to get rid of?

Comment: http://draidel.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/04/screenshot-draidel.com_.ar-2016-04-20-09-11-52.png (its the same element, just displaying an older post)

Comment: So like we talked about in chat, that screenshot doesn't look anything like what I'm seeing in chrome/firefox/IE11 etc in a windows machine.